# outer measure of set equals outer measure of closure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Giving the outer measure for $E \subset\mathbb{R}^n$

$\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\lbrace\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \textrm{diam}(U_i) | E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i\right\rbrace$

we want to prove

$\mu^*(E)= \mu^*(\overline{E})$

for every $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded and connected. In this context we have already proven that the cover of $E$ can be taken open. Furthermore we have proven

$\textrm{diam}(E) = \textrm{diam}(\overline{E})$

We have already proven that a bounded and connected set $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satifies

$\textrm{diam}(\overline{E})= \mu^*(\overline{E})$.

Hope somebody can help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is bounded and connected, you can prove that $\mu^*(E)=\operatorname{diam}(E)$, which gives the desired result.  Clearly $\mu^*(E)\leq \operatorname{diam}(E)$.  Conversely, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x,y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)>\operatorname{diam}(E)-\epsilon$.  For any open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $E$, by connectedness you can find some $i_1,\dots,i_n$ such that $x\in U_{i_1}$, $y\in U_{i_n}$, and $U_{i_k}$ intersects $U_{i_{k+1}}$ for each $k$. The triangle inequality now gives $\sum_k \operatorname{diam}(U_{i_k})\geq d(x,y)=\operatorname{diam}(E)-\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one doubt: like I used compactness so assure certain form of finiteness, how do I know hat there are just finite open sets who connects   $ x$ and $y$? Like you said, it is by connectedness, but which property of connectedness is that?

Comment: The condition on $x$ and $y$ that such $i_1,\dots,i_n$ exist is an equivalence relation, and each equivalence class is a union of $U_i$s and hence open.  I don't know how you could prove the closed case without making essentially the same argument.

Comment: i actually dont really know what do you mean with the equivalence relation?

Comment: Write $x\sim y$ iff there exist $i_1,\dots,i_n$ such that $x\in U_{i_1}$, $y\in U_{i_n}$, and $U_{i_k}\cap U_{i_{k+1}}\neq \emptyset$ for each $k$.  Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $E$.  Just taking a finite subcover in the closed case doesn't tell you anything useful; you need to use connectedness.

Comment: Sorry if I was overly sketchy about the details of this argument; I assumed you would be familiar with a similar argument from having handled the closed case.

Comment: Don't worry. Thank you for helping me :) I actually used a similar argument, but I meant that in the compact case I know that with your defined equivalence relation every two elements of E are in the same class. Now when you dont have compactness, how do you know that $x,y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)>\operatorname{diam}(E)-\epsilon$ have to be in the same class?

Comment: I don't see how compactness helps with anything.  Each equivalence class is an open subset of $E$ (and hence also closed since its complement is the union of the other equivalence classes), so by connectedness, there is only one equivalence class.

Comment: I do not see why a union of $U_i$ are open subsets of E?  if they just cover $ E $ that does no mean that they are contained in $E$...?

Comment: I meant their the intersection with $E$.

Comment: ok, that is what I thought! so I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This is an elaboration of a number of elements of Eric's answer:

We need three results (which you should prove separately):

Suppose $A$ is connected and there is a family of connected sets $C_\alpha$, $\alpha \in I$ such that $A \subset \cup_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$ and $A \cap C_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ for all $\alpha$. Then the set $\cup_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$ is connected.

If $U$ is open and connected, then any two points can be connected by a
path (a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $U$).

We have $\operatorname{diam} A = \operatorname{diam} (\operatorname{co} A)$
(the convex hull of $A$). In particular, we may take the $U_k$ in the
definition of $\mu^*$ to be convex (hence connected).

Choose $x,y \in E$ such that $\|x-y\| > \operatorname{diam} E - \epsilon$.
Let $U_k$ be a collection of open, convex sets that cover $E$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $E$ intersects each $U_k$ (or discard those
that don't).

Then $U=\cup_k U_k$ is open and connected, hence there is a path $p$
from $x$ to $y$ in $U$. However, we need to modify the path so that there is
no "double counting" when we (eventually) use the formula $\sum_k \operatorname{diam} U_k$. The construction is simple in nature but
tedious in detail.

Since $p([0,1])$ is compact, the path lies in $\cup_{k \in I} U_k$, where $I$
is a finite index set. Let $t_0 = 0$, $x_0 = x$, and choose $k_0 \in I$ such that
$x_0 \in U_{k_0}$. Define $t_1 = \sup \{ t \in [t_0,1]| p(t) \in U_{k_0} \}$.
Note that $t_1 \in \overline{U_{k_0}}$, and $p([t_1,1])$ does not intersect
$U_{k_0}$.

If $t_1 = 1$ we are finished. Otherwise we proceed by induction, assuming
that we have $t_0 <t_1<...<t_j<1$, $x_i = p(t_i)$ and $x_i \in U_{k_i}$ for $i=0,...,j$ with $k_i \in I$, and $t_i = \sup \{ t \in [t_{i-1},1]| p(t) \in U_{k_{i-1}} \}$,
for $i=1,...,j$. Also note that the $U_{k_0},...,U_{k_{j}}$ are distinct,
$t_{i+1} \in \overline{U_{k_i}}$ for $i=0,...,j-1$,
and $p([t_j,1])$ does not intersect $U_{k_0} \cup \cdots \cup U_{k_{j-1}}$.

Now, let $t_{j+1} = \sup \{ t \in [t_{j},1]| p(t) \in U_{k_{j}} \}$. If
$t_{j+1}=1$ we are finished, otherwise
choose $k_{j+1} \in I$ such that $t_{j+1} \in U_{k_{j+1}}$.

Since $I$ is finite, there must be some $n$ such that $t_n=1$ and hence $x_n = p(1) = y$.

The points satisfy $[x_i, x_{i+1}) \subset U_{k_i}$, $i=0,...,n-1$, and the
$k_i$ are distinct. Hence
$\sum_k \operatorname{diam} U_k \ge \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{diam} U_{k_i} \ge\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{diam} [x_i, x_{i+1}) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \|x_{i+1}-x_i\|$. The triangle inequality shows that
$\|x-y\| \le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \|x_{i+1}-x_i\|$, and so we have
$\mu^* E \ge \operatorname{diam} E$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood it all perfectly :)